# How to replace first n occurrences of a character for each line?

Tags: vim

Suppose, I have

```
type,type,type,type,description,description,description.  
type,type,type,type,description,description.
```

I want to -

```
type|type|type|type|description,description,description. 
type|type|type|type|description,description.
```

Where I have no I idea about the content of the file. Just I know that I have to substitute first `n` occurrence of `,` with `|` for each line.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing sofisticated but it get's the job done

```
:%norm f,r|;.;.;.
```

#### breakdown

```
:%norm       start a normal command on all lines
f,r|        f(ind) a ',' and r(eplace) with '|'
;.;.;.      ';' jumps to next match and '.' repeats the change
```

Comment: how can replace the comma with and empty char..

Comment: @BharatSoni - `:%norm f,r ;.;.;.`

Answer (score -1):

I guess it could solve your problem

```
:%s/\v(type)./\1|/g

\v ......... very magic to avoid "\"
(type) ..... group 1
.   ........ any char (in our case ,)
\1 ......... back reference to group 1
| .......... literal |
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a macro.
Create a macro. Repeat it on all lines. Done.